# How to make input component using formcontrolname

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I tried a lot of things but not found any solution for this. My question is, how to make input component using `formControlName`?

Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to create a custom component that acts as a form input, you're component will need to implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface.  https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor ,  I also did a blog post covering how to create custom form controls.  https://jasonwhite.xyz/posts/2020/05/22/creating-an-angular-component-library-toggle-switch-component/

Answer (score 0):

You have to import ReactiveFormsModule in module holding your template and then simply

```
<input formControlName="name" />
```